# Laravel Sentry authenticate should not be called statically?

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

In my login controller, I'm trying to authenticate the user credentials with Sentry. I'm getting the error that `Sentry::authenticate` should not be called statically.

Where and how should I call the authenticate function correctly?

```
$usr = Sentry::authenticate($credentials);
```

Comment: Perhaps missing facade? I am not sure.

Comment: You are either missing facade or maybe using wrong ```use``` statement at the top of your controller. There is a difference between ```use Sentry``` and ```use Cartalyst\Sentry\Sentry```.